# Hexeditor that allows finding files among the data

Tags: file

So there are tools that can search a disk, and tell from the data patterns what files are there. But is there any hexeditor tool that can do this too?

Comment: Why do you need a hexeditor tool to find files? Can't you just find the files first and then open them?

Comment: Not if they are inside an archive format that can't be opened normally.

Comment: So your goal is search through a compressed file? That's not that difficult to do with standard unix tools like `tar` and `grep`

Comment: You should try to rephrase your question to tell people what your goal is, rather than what you think is the answer. This is sometimes called an XY problem =)